# Verilog: Can I chain nonblocking assignments?

Tags: fpga, verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to find the most human-readable way to pipeline some logic in system verilog. Most of my delays are routing delays. Is it valid to write something like this?

```
regA <= regA_pipe <= (combinational logic);
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the second `<=` gets interpreted as a less-than-or-equal-to operator.

You could create a macro

```
`define PIPE(Areg, Alogic) begin \
 type(Areg) Areg``_pipe; \
 Areg``_pipe <= Alogic; \ 
 Aref <= Areg``_pipe; end

`PIPE(regA, (combinational logic) )
```

Simulation and behavioral synthesis tools can accept the following Verilog code:

```
regA <= repeat(2) @(posedge clk) (combinational logic);
```

Which reads: after 2 clock cycles regA gets assigned with the result of the combinational logic. But your typical FPGA synthesis tool cannot handle this.